# what the best option to deal with a rusting screw in drywall?

Tags: drywall, screws, patching-drywall

I have some rusting screw in my garage drywall:

[image]

What's the best option to deal with it?

Do I

- drive it back into, spackle it with Drywall Joint Compound and touch it up with paint?
- Remove it somehow, fill the hole with Drywall Joint Compound and touch it up with paint?
- Something else?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rust will continue to rust.

Remove it (them) and replace it (them) with coated drywall screws, which resist rust.

Then fill and paint.

P.S. The cause of the rust may be a leak in the wall behind the board. If so, you have a bigger problem that this cosmetic fix will not solve.